# How to automate creation of PowerPlatform Connector for the API's published in Azure APIM?

Tags: azure-pipelines, azure-api-management, azure-bicep

I have a DevOps pipeline that publishes and API to APIM using Bicep files.  I want to take this further and automatically create Power Platform connector.  Currently this is done using Create Connector/Update Connector feature of Azure Portal.  How to automate this through Azure DevOps pipeline?

[image]

**Update 26/2/24:**  I couldn't find any documentation to achieve this, the publishing of Api was done using Bicep namespace 'Microsoft.ApiManagement/service/apis' which doesn't have support for Portal Connector publishing.  Are there other namespaces which provide this capability? Note, the 'Microsoft.Web/connections' appears to be only for Azure logic apps.

Comment: Is this  [the document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.powerplatform/enterprisepolicies/privateendpointconnections?pivots=deployment-language-bicep) you need？

Comment: @MiaoTian-MSFT: No, the link points to private endpoint between Azure Network and Power Platform Environment.  I am looking for creating the [Connector](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/connectors) in Power Platform for the API's in the Azure APIM.